# Null pointer Exception while a starting HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am new to hive technology. 
I have been trying to setup hive in my machine . By whenever i try to start hive by executing hive shell script in bin folder it give a Null pointer execution and finally ExceptionInInitializerError.

Following is the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load shims in class null
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:248)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:120)
        ... 11 more
```

Does any one know how to resolve it ?
I am using apache-hive-0.13.1
and hadoop-0.22.0 .

Comment: how did you install hive , cloudera manager or tar ball ?

Comment: did you just try using hive command

Comment: yes i tried... Now its resolved .. i think it was some compatibility issue .. using latest hadoop and hive now and its working